# Visual Studio 2015 update2 connectivity issue with Mac while working with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin.iOS and just started to build an iOS app using Xamarin and VS2015 update2. I believe I have all the required softwares to get started. While trying to connect to my Mac machine,  when I try to add my Mac for Xamarin Mac Agent, it is allowing me to type my credentials but it gives me error:

> Couldn't connect to . Please try again"

And when I look into the log I see an entry:

> Service exited with abnormal code: 255

Note that :

- Both my windows machine (Windows 8) and Mac (OS X El Capitan ver
  10.11) are running on same network
- Remote Login is enabled in Mac

I have tried all that is written @https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/ as well, but still I am getting this issue.

Do I need to install anything else in my Mac besides XCode ?

Please help as I am stuck with this issue since last few days.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the Xamarin tools on the OS X side.  xamarin.com/download

I'd imagine if you dig into your Xamarin logs you'll see it can't find mono.

Do that then restart your OS X computer, then your windows computer.

I literally had to restart both before it would work.

Then I was able to login with my domain account on both machines, I'm sure I could have used a local admin account as well.

FYI: I'm running VS2015 Update 3 on Win10 in VMWare Fusion on my Mac which is El Capitan 10.11.6 which is also the host I'm remotely logging into.